# Add variables into an interation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iterator

I would like to use a variable present into my partial to change the result of my iteration. To illustrate that let's take an example to be more explicit.

My variable would be @cat = 2

And I would like to run this iteration :

```
Post.where(cat#{@cat}: true).each do |post|
```

Witch should give that :

```
Post.where(cat2: true).each do |post|
```

But I don't know how I can do it. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string interpolation to achieve this. Check the below example:

```
@variable = 'column'
Post.where("post_#{@variable}": true).each {|x| puts x.inspect}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhilash Reddy, that's exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

In this case `cat2` is not a "variable", but a symbol/string, which makes it easier. This should work as desired:

```
 Post.where("cat#{@cat}" => true).each do |post|
```

In general case, however, it's a very bad idea to generate variable names like that. It's a sign that you've likely chosen a wrong data structure for the job.

Answer (score 1):

try this code, suggestions are welcome

```
@cat = 2

Post.where(:"cat#{@cat}" => true).each do |post|
```

Comment: No need for symbolizing, btw. Strings would work just as well.